# Spring annotation with name

Tags: spring

I'm newbie and I have a question as below.
Can anyone explain for me about annotation with name in spring? What is difference among examples as below:

> example 1:

```
@Service
public class A{...}
```

> example 2:

```
@Service("nameA")
public class A{...}
```

Comment: Don't be *[that guy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/8679)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example:

```
@Service("nameA")
public class A{...}
```

Gives this service a name. You can then autowire the bean in this manner:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("nameA")
private A a;
```

This isn't particularly useful in your example. But consider if you're using XML config:

```
<bean id="thisIsAQualifier" class="A"/>
<bean id="thisIsAnotherQualifier" class="A"/>
```

You can now autowire either of these with the `@Qualifier` annotation even though they are both the same class.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("thisIsAQualifier")
private A a;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("thisIsAnotherQualifier")
private A a2;
```

Without qualifiers, you would receive the `No unique bean` error, as there would be two beans of type `A`.